# How to use pyramid cookie to authenticate user in tornado web framework?

Tags: python, session, cookies, tornado, pyramid

In a server, I have a pyramid app running and I plan to have another tornado app running in parallel in the same machine. Let's say the pyramid app is available in www.abcd.com, then the tornado app will be available in www.abcd.com:9000.

I want only the authenticated users in the pyramid webapp to be able to access the tornado webapp.

My guess is somehow using cookie set by the pyramid app in tornado.

Is it possible? What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The two locations are separate origins in HTTP language. By default, they should not share cookies.

Before trying to figure out how to pass cookies around I'd try to set up a front end web server like Nginx that would proxy requests between two different backend servers. Both applications could get their own path, served from www.abcd.com.